# Tensorflow1，How to calculate tensor's cosin-similarity to form a similarity matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cosine-similarity, distance-matrix

First,I have a tensor like this,

```
a = [[A B],[C D]]
```

I'd like to calculate cosin-similarity between each other,I mean calculate cos([A B],[A B]),cos([A B],[C D]),cos([C D],[A B]),cos([C D],[C D]) to form a similarity matrix like this,

```
[[cos([A B],[A B]),cos([A B],[C D])],
 [cos([C D],[A B]),cos([C D],[C D])]]
```

I want to use follow code to get similarity matrix,it did't work.

```
`tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.expand_dims(a, 0),
 tf.expand_dims(a, 1), axis = 2)`
```

How to use efficient vectorization to do this work in TF1?thank your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = [1.,2.,3.]
b = [1.,2.,3.]
#cosine_similarity = tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, 0), tf.nn.l2_normalize(b, 0), dim=0)  ##normalize_input
cosine_similarity = tf.losses.cosine_distance(a, b, dim=0)
print(tf.Session().run(cosine_similarity))
```

output

```
-13.0
```